Automatically calculate a column that gets incremented based on another timestamp column
I have a created_at column and I would like to create a new column whose name gets incremented depending on the week on which the created_at appears. For example, I have the column (timestamp format) :
created_at
------------
2024-04-08 
2024-04-09
2024-04-13 
2024-04-15
2024-04-16
2024-04-18
2024-04-22
2024-04-25

and I would like to produce the following :
created_at   | new_column
---------------------------------
2024-04-08     C10
2024-04-09     C10
2024-04-13     C10
2024-04-15     C11
2024-04-16     C11
2024-04-18     C11
2024-04-22     C12
2024-04-25     C12

For now I am doing it manually :
SELECT
        created_at
        , CASE
            WHEN DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)::DATE = '2024-04-08'::DATE THEN 'C10'
            WHEN DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)::DATE = '2024-04-15'::DATE THEN 'C11'
            WHEN DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)::DATE = '2024-04-22'::DATE THEN 'C12'
        END AS new_columns    
FROM my_table  

 

but I would like to automate it instead of creating a new WHEN statement each time.

Use date_part function:
SELECT t, 'C' || date_part('week', t)::TEXT
FROM generate_series('2024-01-01'::timestamp, '2025-01-01'::timestamp, '3 day'::interval) AS t;

It returns week indexed text:
...
"2024-03-04 00:00:00"   "C10"
"2024-03-07 00:00:00"   "C10"
"2024-03-10 00:00:00"   "C10"
"2024-03-13 00:00:00"   "C11"
"2024-03-16 00:00:00"   "C11"
"2024-03-19 00:00:00"   "C12"
"2024-03-22 00:00:00"   "C12"
"2024-03-25 00:00:00"   "C13"
"2024-03-28 00:00:00"   "C13"
...

For your use case it boils down to:
SELECT
    created_at,
    'C' || date_part('week', created_at)::TEXT AS week_index
FROM my_table;


ah ! it was the generate_series command that I needed

If the above answer resolved your issue, or lead you to the solution, then kindly accept it. This aids future users having the same or similar issues and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave a successfully answered question as unanswered.

hi ! i am testing it first, I think the 3 days interval does not work, and instead it should be 1 week

There is nothing magic with 3 days, it just spans for dates regularity to generate some basic input. I expect the column to exist as you stated in your post and I kind of mimic it with generate_series. The key point here is to avoid CASE in favor of the simple operation of date_part.

@jlandercy You might want to spell it out explicitly as SELECT created_at, 'C' || date_part('week', created_at)::text as new_columns FROM my_table

@dada, updated the answer to comply with your use case.

thx validated now :))
